# firewalld has 443 enabled but it refuses connections

Tags: centos7, firewalld

I'm on centos 7 using firewalld.

I've configured firewalld so 443 is open:

```
$ sudo firewall-cmd --zone=public --permanent --list-all
public
  target: default
  icmp-block-inversion: no
  interfaces: 
  sources: 
  services: couchdb2 dhcpv6-client http https ssh
  ports: 443/tcp 5984/tcp
  protocols: 
  masquerade: no
  forward-ports: 
  sourceports: 
  icmp-blocks: 
  rich rules: 

$ sudo firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-port=443/tcp --permanent
Warning: ALREADY_ENABLED: 443:tcp
success
```

apparently port 443 is open, but ...

```
$ curl https://127.0.0.1:443
curl: (7) Failed connect to 127.0.0.1:443; Connection refused
```

I also test it using the web tool at http://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/open-ports/

I type in my IP address and port 443 and get: Closed Port 443 is closed on {my-ip}

What could be going wrong? It seems to open and yet it isn't.

I query netstat with this result:

```
$ sudo netstat -lnp | grep 443
udp        0      0 127.0.0.1:323           0.0.0.0:*                           
443/chronyd         
udp6       0      0 ::1:323                 :::*                                
443/chronyd
```

Once I fixed my nginx.conf to properly listen to 443 the result looked like:

```
$ sudo netstat -lnp | grep 443
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:443             0.0.0.0:*               
LISTEN      10197/nginx: master 
tcp6       0      0 :::443                  :::*                    
LISTEN      10197/nginx: master 
udp        0      0 127.0.0.1:323           0.0.0.0:*                           
443/chronyd         
udp6       0      0 ::1:323                 :::*                                
443/chronyd
```

Comment: It's better to include the leading colon when you're looking for a specific port.  (i.e. "sudo netstat -lnp | grep :443")  The output you've shown only matches because chronyd happens to have process id 443.

Comment: **Check points** 1. Port should be allowed on network (Firewalld/iptables/net etc) 2. Server should listen the port (apache2.conf/httpd.conf etc)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error **Connection refused** usually means the firewall allowed the packets to get through (unless the firewall is actively rejecting the connection attempt), but there is no service listening on the destined port number.

In your case, you need to make sure an HTTPs web server is running and listening port 443. You can use the following command to verify.

```
sudo netstat -lnp | grep 443
```

**Edit:** As commented by @Paul, the shown output means there is no process listening on port 443. The output is irrelevant because the process ID matched 443 and we need it to match with port number of TCP protocol. You need to find a line similar to:

```
tcp  0   0 0.0.0.0:443      0.0.0.0:*     LISTEN      <pid>/<proc_name>
```

Comment: This, and additionally, some cloud services like Amazon AWS have their own firewall/security systems where you need to open the ports there too. In AWS EC2 you have security groups where you need to again specify who you allow where.

Comment: @JayMcTee I'm not on AWS, I'm using bare metal CentOS 7

Comment: @Khaled I'm using nginx as my webserver, and its configured using the nginx.conf and a sites-enabled module to listen to 443. Is that what you mean? My netstat output is added to your answer above

Comment: @Khaled Not sure if you can see my output above yet. Its says it has to be peer reviewed. I'll put it here too with crappy formatting: 'code'udp        0      0 127.0.0.1:323           0.0.0.0:*                           443/chronyd         
udp6       0      0 ::1:323                 :::*                                443/chronyd 'code'

Comment: @Khaled you can read the output better in the Question itself now

Comment: @Khaled Yes, it was my nginx.conf that needed fixing. I was confident I had it right and I did, but the wrong file got copied to the server. :-/ Sorry to waste your time.

Answer (score 0):

You need to reload `firewalld` after you add a rule with `--permanent` or you have to rerun the command without `--permanent`.

When you say `--permanent` firewalld just updates the configuration, but doesn't reload it.

Comment: $ sudo firewall-cmd --zone=public --permanent --list-all appears to reflect the current state, not just the config. I experimented with closing and opening the port. But reloading the config didn't change anything.

Comment: It turned out to just be my nginx.conf